# SQL Join and Json encode joomla 2.5

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, joomla2.5, json

Okay ill be honest im a little bit lost here, Im creating a component for joomla 2.5 and have two tables in the database, "managers" and another called "Branches". Im trying to join managers with branches.

I wish i could be more precise with my problem but i honestly dont understand it, heres my model file that calls to the database:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

 jimport('joomla.application.component.model');

class LocateModelBranches extends JModel
{
public function getItem()
{
    $branch_id = JRequest::getInt('id');

    $row = JTable::getInstance('branches', 'LocateTable');
    $row->load($branch_id);

    return $row;
}

public function getBranches()
{
    $branch_id = JRequest::getInt('id');

    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('*');
    $query->from('#__branches');
    $query->join('LEFT', '#__managers AS a USING(manager_id)');
    $query->where("published = 1");

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $rows;
}
}
```

then my view.json.php file:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

jimport( 'joomla.application.component.view');

class LocateViewBranches extends JView
{
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $branch = $this->get('Branches');
    $response = array();

    foreach ($branch as $row) {
            $response[] = array(
                    'lat' => $row->branch_latitude,
                    'lng' => $row->branch_longitude,
                    'data' => array(
                        'name' => $row->branch_name,
                        'address' => $row->branch_address,
                        'fax' => $row->branch_fax,
                        'email' => $row->branch_email,
                        'city' => $row->branch_city,
                        'telephone' => $row->branch_telephone,
                        'id' => $row->branch_id,
                        'lati' => $row->branch_latitude,
                        'lngi' => $row->branch_longitude,
                        'manager_id' => $row->manager_id,
                    ),
                );
        }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
}
```

then i get a response of:

```
[]
```

if i remove "$query->join('LEFT', '#__managers AS a USING(manager_id)');" my response then is (which is what i want along with the managers details :

```
[{"lat":"-33.9249","lng":"18.4241","data":{"name":"test 2","address":"greenpoint, Cape Town","fax":"044 382 0605","email":"test","city":"blah","telephone":"044 382 0605","id":"2","lati":"-33.9249","lngi":"18.4241"}},{"lat":"-34.0438","lng":"23.0759","data":{"name":"jam factory","address":"15 meeu street knysna","fax":"00000000","email":"00000000","city":"am factory","telephone":"0000000","id":"14","lati":"-34.0438","lngi":"23.0759"}}]
```

Im sure its just a problem with my view.json.php

also if i change from json_encode to print_r and keep "$query->join('LEFT', '#__managers AS a USING(manager_id)');" i get a response of:

```
Array
 (
 )
 1
```

so surely its just the way im outputting the data

Comment: As you did not post your tables schema, I must ask you if in the LEFT JOIN condition the column manager_id exists in both tables.

Comment: well are you referring to the tables in the database? Thank you so much for your response... If so then yes it is in both tables

Comment: Try replacing $db = $this->getDbo(); to $db = JFactory::getDBO();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy as:

```
    public function getBranches()
{
    $branch_id = JRequest::getInt('id');

    $db = $this->getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query->select('*, a.manager_name,manager_mobile');
    $query->from('#__branches AS t')
            ->join('LEFT', '#__managers AS a USING(manager_id)')
            ->where('t.published = 1');

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

    return $rows;
}
```

Thanks For everyone's input. :)